# time and random module in python

Tags: python, datetime, random

I'm so basic in python
my code work but the output is similar every time and it's not the correct answer

```
import datetime
import time
import random

odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33,
       35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59]

minutee = datetime.datetime.today().minute
for i in range (5):     
     if minutee in odd:
          print ('odd')
     else:
          print('not odd')    
     wait_time= random.randint(1,40)    
     time.sleep(wait_time)
```

Comment: What is the expected result?

Comment: @VasilisG. the program read my device's time and read it's minute and print odd or not odd in rang (5) with a random delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you calculate `minutee` before the for loop and it's never updated. Here is the correct code:

```
import datetime
import time
import random

odd = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9, 11, 13, 15, 17, 19, 21, 23, 25, 27, 29, 31, 33,
       35, 37, 39, 41, 43, 45, 47, 49, 51, 53, 55, 57, 59]


for i in range (5):
    minutee = datetime.datetime.today().minute
    if minutee in odd:
        print ('odd')
    else:
        print('not odd')
    wait_time= random.randint(1,40)
    time.sleep(wait_time)
```